# Typescript - Can't type the style root

Tags: typescript, types, material-ui, styles, tsx

I think that I have to code the following types that the error gives in the root tag:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(style: Styles<Theme, {}, "root">, options?: Pick<WithStylesOptions<Theme>, "flip" | "element" | "defaultTheme" | "name" | "media" | "meta" | "index" | "link" | "generateId" | "classNamePrefix">): (props?: any) => Record<...>', gave the following error.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>>'
```

The problem is that I just don't know how to do it, never typed nothing like this before. You can find the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pedroRelvas/HowToTypeTheStyleRoot (You can find the error on the file demo.tsx). Can you explain it to me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: `
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fe6b8b 30%, #ff8e53 90%);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, 0.3);
  ` as CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>>,
});
```